# Are java or c# projects still being build without using IDE

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, maven

I was Reading a tutorial on MVN in that he is explaining how to build the project using Commands in terminal using apache maven. I have eclipse installed on my system and did the samples using it so I am thinking that why to read about CLI as we are having lot of good IDE's (eclipse,sts,visual studio(c#) etc). So will it be helpful for reading about CLI commands.

Comment: This is probably a question more for programmers.stackexchange.com. But I would imagine the answer is yes, especially in places where getting hold of software is tricky (i.e no internet/retail outlets).. of course these particular users would never be able to answer your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely.  Command line builds are typically used in automated build systems, or if you're doing a build remotely and don't have access to the IDE.

Apart from practical considerations, learning to do the builds from the commandline will give you a better understanding of how all the different components in a build system function together.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get beyond tutorials, you won't want to have to click several buttons to build and package your project. This is why there are automated build tools, which are typically triggered via a command line.

Someone will have to configure this automated build, and in a modern project setup, this is in the responsibility of the developers. So, yes, you need to learn about automated build tools and their configuration & commands.